# Does localeCompare() method in JS uses ASCII code for comparing Two Strings?

Tags: javascript, string

I wonder if localeCompare() method uses ASCII code or Unicode for comparing two strings.

I guess it uses unicode because it includes more chars so JavaScript can compare every strings but
the problem of unicode is that it uses more storage (I think twice of ASCII code) so I'm not sure which one does JavaScript uses.

Comment: JavaScript strings are encoded internally in UTF-16, with some quirks for characters that require more than 2 bytes. But that's an implementation detail that's transparent for most of the usages. And encoding is not the same as collation. You have an overview in [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) say it calls [Intl.Collator.compare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/compare) which defers to the given locale's sort ordering, which may or may not be based directly on Unicode codepoints. (For example, IIRC German collates u and ü next to each other, despite them not being anywhere near each other as Unicode codepoints.)

That aside, all of this uses Unicode - it just so happens (IOW, it was purposely designed so) the 127 first Unicode codepoints directly correspond to 7-bit ASCII "codepoints".

As a second aside, Unicode itself doesn't use any storage at all - an Unicode encoding does. UTF-8 uses the 1 byte per character for codepoints <= 127, and more thereafter; UTF-16 uses 2 bytes for all characters <= 65535 and more thereafter; UTF-32 uses 4 bytes for each of 4 billion characters.